# Jackson: allow property naming strategy to work with @JsonCreator

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize/deserialize immutable POJOs. As the POJOs are immutable, I am defining them like this:

```
class Foo {
    private final String bar;
    private final String wibbleBoing;

    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(@JsonProperty("bar") String bar, @JsonProperty("wibbleBoing") wibbleBoing) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.wibbleBoing = wibbleBoing;
    }

    ... [getters] ...
}
```

I am forced to use `@JsonProperty` on the constructor arguments as the Java bytecode does not contain the parameter names. [actually, I am aware that it *can* do for Java 8, and I *could* use `jackson-module-parameter-names` to circumvent that, but this is not an option for me right now].

Now, let's suppose that I also want to use a property naming strategy, so that I can change all property names to lower-case-with-underscores rather than camel case, and in such a way that I don't have to change my existing POJOs.

In Jackson 2.3, this worked a treat. However, in Jackson 2.4, the explicit naming of `@JsonProperty`-annotated constructor arguments seems to have trumped the naming strategy.

Renaming all of the `@JsonProperty` annotations in my POJOs is a leaky abstraction that I'd rather not do... so is there another way that I can set up my mapper or do something globally to apply the property naming strategy to such constructor arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try a later version: at least 2.5(.4), or 2.6.0-rc2 (official 2.6.0 should be out soon, but until then).
There are known bugs in this area, resulting from division between implicit names (getter/setter, field, constructor parameter names) and explicit overrides (like `@JsonProperty`). 2.6.0 fixes these; I am not 100% sure if all are backported in 2.5 or not.

If you must use an earlier version, you may be able to fix the problem by sub-classing `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and overriding `findNameForSerialization()`, `findNameForDeserialization()` and `findImplicitPropertyName()` (or something close to those, see javadocs), and adding conversions there. This would be a work-around, but allows you to get things working until version that works as expected.

Comment: Thanks- this works by overriding `findNameForDeserialization` and `findImplicitPropertyName`. The trick is to make Jackson believe that the declaration is implicit rather than explicit, by making `findNameForDeserialization` return `null` and making `findImplicitPropertyName` return the value instead. Ugh.